# One PS+ Plus account on primary ps4 allow multiplayer on Call of Duty to all local accounts?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, playstation-plus

Myself and three brothers share one PS4. We have an account with ps+ subscritpion we all share. I was wondering if we made two more local accounts if each of those accounts would be able to play Black Ops 3 multiplayer under seperate online psn accounts when it comes out? The PS4 account is activated as out primary ps4.

Answer (score 1):

You can make two more PSN accounts and then make them as sub accounts under Settings > Parental Controls > Sub Account Management in the account that has PS+

Comment: Do sub accounts not share the master account's PS+ subscription?

Comment: Yes, they share the PS+